# Using partial classes for validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework to create my data objects. Here's what my designer.cs file looks like:

```
namespace MyApp.WebUI.Models
{
    ...

    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MyAppDBModel", Name="AddressType")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class AddressType : EntityObject
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I have a file called Validation.cs in which I want to keep all my validation for my entities. Here's what it looks like:

```
namespace MyApp.WebUI.Models
{
    public class Validations
    {
        ...

        [MetadataType(typeof(AddressTypesValidation))]
        public partial class AddressType
        {

        }

        public class AddressTypesValidation
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Type name is required.")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Address Type name must be 50 characters or less.")]
            public string Name { get; set; }                
        }
    }
}
```

I have this in my view page:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "AddressTypes", FormMethod.Post)) { %>

    <div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) %></div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name) %>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

<% } %>
```

But my validations aren't loaded. If I try to submit the form with no value for Name, I get an error message saying `The value '' is invalid.` instead of my error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw with your approach. It is generally understood that using your database objects as view models and having Mvc do its model binding on them is a **very bad idea.**

Darin has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878937/why-should-i-use-view-models/4878956#4878956) detailing the issues associated with using domain objects in views.

I think your issues are being caused because you're mix data objects with view models, and to quote Darin

> About 60% of the question I am [Darin]
>   answering on StackOverflow in the
>   asp.net-mvc tag wouldn't have been
>   asked if the OP have used a view
>   model.

Comment: I agree that using viewmodels is the way to go - but isn't it still possible to put validation on the business objects themselves?  The viewmodel ultimately wraps those same properties, and I would think it's better to put the validation in one place - near the database - than replicate it across potentially multiple UI-focused implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can have a partial class then have another partial class that is a nested class.  Try having the partial you've declared not be a nested class.

Edit:
Just ran a quick test in VS (not the validation part) and you can't one part of a partial class in a nested type and have another part of the partial class as a non-nested type (or nested in a different type).

Answer (score 0):

I may be off the mark here, but I believe that the `Required` attribute simply means 'not null', and your `StringLengthValidator` is only checking for an upper bound.  It's not failing because you are sending through a string - unfortunately it's the `String.Empty`.

You're using the overload

```
[StringLength(int upperBound, [Parameters])]
```

Instead, try

```
[StringLength(int lowerBound, int upperBound, [Parameters])]
```

something like this, if you want minimum length of 1:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Type name is required.")]               
[StringLength(1, 50, ErrorMessage = "Address Type...")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```