# bootstrap3 modal not wotking in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show an ASP.NET MVC PartialView in a bootstrap 3 modal.

I use this solution:
[MVC 4 Edit modal form using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011151/mvc-4-edit-modal-form-using-bootstrap/16011752#16011752)

but only modal overlay was shown like below.
Please help

[image: my error]

Comment: How about posting some code?

Comment: Try [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19039695/894273). I just updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bootstrap 2 modal dialog which should be upgraded to version 3 this way:

- remove the `hide` class (that's the reason of showing that overlay)
- move `modal-header`، `modal-body` and `modal-footer` classes into a `div` with `modal-content` class.
- `modal-content` should be placed inside the `modal-dialog` class.