# MVC4: populate a drop down list from a custom class

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class that I populate when a user navigates to a certain page, /Home/About, within my MVC4 application.  I populate a class with data and I would like to have in my view that data in a drop down list.

My class looks like this: (UPDATED)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class WorkSection : List<WorkSection>
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "WorkSection")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public SelectList WorkSections { get; set; }

    public WorkSection()
    {
        // Default Constructor
    }

    public WorkSection(int id, string code)
    {
        this.ID = ws_id;
        this.Code = code;
    }
}
```

How do I take this populated List of type WorkSection and make that the data source for my drop down list?  I would like to display the Code and Source field in a concatenated fashion, like "Code:Source" within the drop down list with the ID as the selected item's value.

UPDATE for ActionResult, where code will be called from on /Home/About

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        WorkSection model = new WorkSection();
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "omitted";

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        try
        {
            OracleDataReader reader = null;
            // Work Section
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT ID, CODE FROM MyTable ORDER BY CODE", con);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                model.Add(new WorkSection()
                {
                    ID = Int16.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString()),
                    Code = reader["CODE"].ToString()
                });
            }

            model.WorkSections = BuildSelectList(model.WorkSections, m => m.ID, m => m.Code);

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, we need a view model to encapsulate the data for the view:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Work section")]
    // This represents the selected ID on the dropdown
    public int WorkSectionId { get; set; }
    // The dropdown itself
    public SelectList WorkSections { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Next up, we need a way to populate the `SelectList`.  I wrote a custom method a while ago to do just that:

```
private SelectList BuildSelectList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, int>> valueKey, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> textKey,
    object selectedValue = null)
{
    var selectedValueKey = ((MemberExpression)(MemberExpression)valueKey.Body).Member.Name;
    var selectedTextKey = ((MemberExpression)(MemberExpression)textKey.Body).Member.Name;

    return new SelectList(source, selectedValueKey, selectedTextKey, selectedValue);
}
```

This uses expression trees for type-safety, ensuring problems are caught at compile-time, rather than run-time.  `SelectList` also uses one property for the text key and one for the value key.  In your situation, this obviously creates a problem, because you want to combine `Code` and `Source` to form the text key.  In order to get around that, you'll need to create a new property in `WorkSection` that combines both:

```
public string CodeSource
{
    get { return this.Code + ":" + this.Source; }
}
```

That way, you can use that to create the `SelectList` as normal.  To do that, your action might like something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var workSections = // ... fetch from database

    TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel();
    model.WorkSections = BuildSelectList(workSections, m => m.ID, m => m.CodeSource);

    return View(model);
}
```

You can use that in the view like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkSectionId, Model.WorkSections, "--Please Select--")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WorkSectionId)
```

One final note on `BuildSelectList`.  The method has saved me a lot of time when dealing with dropdowns in general.  So much so that I now define it as a public method on a base controller, which I then derive all of my controllers from.  However, if you want to do that, you'll want to mark it with the `[NonAction]` attribute so it doesn't interfere with routing.

**Update per comments**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [NonAction]
    public SelectList BuildSelectList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, int>> valueKey, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> textKey,
        object selectedValue = null)
    {
        var selectedValueKey = ((MemberExpression)(MemberExpression)valueKey.Body).Member.Name;
        var selectedTextKey = ((MemberExpression)(MemberExpression)textKey.Body).Member.Name;

        return new SelectList(source, selectedValueKey, selectedTextKey, selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Then you'd derive your controllers from `BaseController` instead:

```
public HomeController : BaseController
{
    // 
}
```

Comment: John, talk to me more about that.....creating a public method on a base controller.  I imagine I create a controller that every other controller inherits from, for example MyController : BaseController? This seems like a really good idea, just want to make sure I get it right.

Comment: @BrianEvans Yeah, that's it mate.  Give me a sec and I'll add an example so you can see it.

Comment: @BrianEvans There we go.

Comment: Ok John, I have updated my class/entity above.  I am left with one error: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @BrianEvans Is `WorkSection` a model that you're passing directly to your view?  My example relied on it being contained in a view model, which is then passed to the view.

Comment: I am updating the code above with the entire ActionResult About() where this code will be called from....

Comment: @BrianEvans Alright, there's a few things going on here.  Firstly, you should really be using view models in your views.  For a really good answer that covers why, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4878956/729541).  That means your view should really be strongly-typed to something like `WorkSectionViewModel`, rather than `WorkSection`, directly.  The initial downside of this is you have to map from models to view models, and vice versa.  However, [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is used for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @BrianEvans It's 4am here, so I should really go, but I do have a working project setup so you can take a look at it.  Would you like me to upload it somewhere before I go, so you can see how it all fits together?

Comment: @BrianEvans You're welcome. :) It's all sent, so you should delete your email address from here so you don't get spammed to death.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`@Hmtl.DropdownListFor(m=>m.YourNameForSelectedWorkSectionId, Model.WorkSections.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Code +":"+x.Source, Value = x.ID}))`